# Good, free source for counting (combinations, permutations) and/or probability?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I'm a freshman CS major and find both of these topics really interesting, but I also find them difficult (I've been told this isn't much of a surprise!).

I was hoping some of you could direct me towards some sources to supplement what I'm learning. I visited a few relevant questions posted before, but the one good one that had sources provided links that are now broken!

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want a book / lecture notes on combinatorics, or you want something that can compute things like ${n \choose k}$?

Comment: I meant books/textbooks/lecture notes on it, not a calculator, since I have one that does such calculations. Thanks, I should have been clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to start off with a Discrete Math textbook, which will introduce you to relevant mathematical preliminaries as a CS major. Certain combinatorial arguments rely on your understanding of functions and basic set theory, plus it helps formalize intuition. So this is really a good starting point. Epp's Discrete Math text is pretty friendly and has a good covering of set theory, functions, relations, basic combinatorics, and graph theory (which is closely tied to combinatorics).

I'd avoid Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics text. It is a good book for problems, but not much else.

Nick Loehr's Bijective Combinatorics text is quite good, but is geared towards advanced undergrads and grad students. It might be a good text for later.

A personal note: I found combinatorics quite perplexing the first time I saw it, which was when I was a senior in high school. I had a good teacher, but didn't get it. I liked it more when I took a class in college, and I've continued to develop an intuition for it. It is quite a difficult subject and requires a lot of intuition. However, it is very rewarding in training your brain and helping in other subjects (such as linear algebra, where you can really utilize bijective counting arguments in your linear transformations unit). Don't get too frustrated if you struggle with it the first time around.

Best of luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel really assured about how your experience was with counting. Most of my math education has come instantly to me, but counting -- although I don't think I'm half bad, I'm not nearly as precocious! I was starting to think that perhaps I just didn't have what it takes!

Comment: Welcome to college and advanced math. Counting gave me a run for my money the first time around. Real analysis really was a humbling experience. There are many other classes like this. Take them. They will push you, and you will grow from them. I think you will be fine at the end of the day. Best of luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement! At the end of the day I just want to know as much math as possible. Woohoo!